# Is it possible to retrieve events later on?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, web3.py, events

The scenario is : There are two participants **A** and **B**.

**A** sends a transaction to a Smart Contract and an event (**X**) is emitted as a result of the transaction.

The event is caught (listened to ? ) by **B**

Maybe the event is a signal for some important operation like payment to A from B etc

What if B later on denies the presence of any event ?

How can we prove, the existence and provenance of the event **X** later on, some time in future ?

Can anyone provide some guidance on this ?

P.S : I am using Python 3.9, Web3.py and solidity on Remix IDE

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/anatomy/#events-and-logs):

> Events let you communicate with your smart contract from your frontend or other subscribing applications. When a transaction is mined, smart contracts can emit events and write logs to the blockchain that the frontend can then process.

Which means that the events are part of the chain and they can be collected at any given moment by listening for events of this topic on the block they were mined.

This blocks anyone from denying the existence of the event.
As long as it was emitted from a smart contract based on a certain operation, it will be there for you to collect and display.

Check out this part of the [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id36) to see how you can listen for events on specific blocks as well.